# How do I return an auto_ptr of a base class using an auto_ptr of a derived class?

Tags: c++

I am working through some older code that must return an `std::auto_ptr`, with which I have relatively little experience. I have run into a situation like this:

```
// I need to populate this function
std::auto_ptr<Base> Func()
{
  std::auto_ptr<Derived> derivedPtr = new Derived;

  // now I want to return

  return derivedPtr; // error: conversion from std::auto_ptr<Derived> to std::auto_ptr<Base> is ambiguous
}
```

Do I need to release auto_ptr first? The really overly explicit way would be something like `return static_cast<Base>(derivedPtr.release())` but I suspect this isn't necessary.

Comment: Dude, I am so so sorry!

Comment: Be sure that `Base` has a virtual destructor before attempting this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use...

```
return std::auto_ptr<Base>(derivedPtr);   // explicitly use constructor
```

...or...

```
return derivedPtr.operator std::auto_ptr<Base>();  // use cast/conversion operator
```

(The reason you can't just return `derivedPtr` is that the above are ambiguous candidates).